# Rank rows in a column under conditions on a different column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, rank

I have the following dataset:

```
 id |   date   | state
-----------------------
  1 | 01/01/17 | high
  1 | 02/01/17 | high
  1 | 03/01/17 | high
  1 | 04/01/17 | miss
  1 | 05/01/17 | high
  2 | 01/01/17 | miss
  2 | 02/01/17 | high
  2 | 03/01/17 | high
  2 | 04/01/17 | miss
  2 | 05/01/17 | miss
  2 | 06/01/17 | high
```

I want to create a column `rank_state` which ranks, within groups of `id`, the entries as per increasing `date` (starting from rank 0) which **do not** have the `state` of "miss". Furthermore, the rank repeats itself if the entry has a `state` of "miss". The output should look like:

```
 id |   date   | state | rank_state
------------------------------------
  1 | 01/01/17 | high  |    0
  1 | 02/01/17 | high  |    1
  1 | 03/01/17 | high  |    2
  1 | 04/01/17 | miss  |    2
  1 | 05/01/17 | high  |    3
  2 | 01/01/17 | miss  |    0
  2 | 02/01/17 | high  |    0
  2 | 03/01/17 | high  |    1
  2 | 04/01/17 | miss  |    1
  2 | 05/01/17 | miss  |    1
  2 | 06/01/17 | high  |    2
```

For example, the 4th row has a rank of 2 since it's `state` is "miss", i.e. it repeats the rank of row 3 (the same applies to rows 9 and 10). Please note that rows 6 and 7 should have rank 0.

I have tried the following:
`,(case when state is not in ('miss') then (rank() over (partition by id order by date desc) - 1) end) as state_rank`
and
`,rank() over (partition by id order by case when state is not in ('miss') then date end) as state_rank`
but neither give me the desired result. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't a help/education forum, not a freelancer forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely you want:

```
SELECT *, 
       GREATEST(
         COUNT(case when state != 'miss' then 1 else null end) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) - 1,
         0
       ) as "state_rank"
FROM tbl;
```

#### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8433c/11)

Basically:

- make your window frame (partition) over`id`
- only count the ones that aren't `'miss'`
- because it could be a negative number if starting the record, you can slap on the `GREATEST` to use 0 (preventing negatives)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @vol7ron. However, I get the following error: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause. Btw, I am using PSQL instead of SQL.

Comment: psql is postrgres. What version? You might be doing something wrong. The fiddle shows it works.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 8.0.2, could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes that would be it. Do you have to use 8.0.2 you should be off it at all costs.  For reasons of security to features, upgrade to 9.3+.  If you have to stay in 8.X, you should be on 8.4

Comment: 8.0 came out in 2005 and it's end of life came in 2010. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/  You should have retired it almost ~10 years ago.

Comment: Thank you. I shall upgrade and give it a shot.

Comment: I cannot use anything later than 8.0.2 since redshift does not support anything later than that. Are there ways to design the code for 8.0.2?

Comment: @labrynth, you should open up a new question and tag Redshift.  It's built on PostgreSQL 8.0.2, but it is a fork.  It doesn't support some of the functions that come with 8.x, but it also has functions that Postgres doesn't have.  It's almost like OSX vs Ubuntu, or bash vs dash, many similar commands, but not everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just add frame_clause to vol7ron's answer since Redshift requires it :

```
select *
    , GREATEST(COUNT(case when state != 'miss' then 1 else null end) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) -1 , 0 ) as state_rank
from tbl;
```