# Ranking based on conditions of a different column in PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Tags: amazon-redshift, window-functions, rank

I have the following dataset:

```
 id |   date   | state
-----------------------
  1 | 01/01/17 | high
  1 | 02/01/17 | high
  1 | 03/01/17 | high
  1 | 04/01/17 | miss
  1 | 05/01/17 | high
  2 | 01/01/17 | miss
  2 | 02/01/17 | high
  2 | 03/01/17 | high
  2 | 04/01/17 | miss
  2 | 05/01/17 | miss
  2 | 06/01/17 | high
```

I want to create, **using PostgreSQL version 8.0.2 (compatible with Redshift)**, a column `rank_state` which ranks, within groups of `id`, the entries as per increasing `date` (starting from rank 0) which **do not** have the `state` of "miss". Furthermore, the rank repeats itself if the entry has a `state` of "miss". The output should look like:

```
 id |   date   | state | rank_state
------------------------------------
  1 | 01/01/17 | high  |    0
  1 | 02/01/17 | high  |    1
  1 | 03/01/17 | high  |    2
  1 | 04/01/17 | miss  |    2
  1 | 05/01/17 | high  |    3
  2 | 01/01/17 | miss  |    0
  2 | 02/01/17 | high  |    0
  2 | 03/01/17 | high  |    1
  2 | 04/01/17 | miss  |    1
  2 | 05/01/17 | miss  |    1
  2 | 06/01/17 | high  |    2
```

For example, the 4th row has a rank of 2 since it's `state` is "miss", i.e. it repeats the rank of row 3 (the same applies to rows 9 and 10). Please note that rows 6 and 7 should have rank 0.

I have tried the following:
`,(case when state is not in ('miss') then (rank() over (partition by id order by date desc) - 1) end) as state_rank`
and
`,rank() over (partition by id order by case when state is not in ('miss') then date end) as state_rank`
but neither give me the desired result. Any ideas would be very helpful.

**The question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164608/rank-rows-in-a-column-under-conditions-on-a-different-column), however I am trying to figure a solution using PostgreSQL version 8.0.2**

Comment: Redshift too can use [`count()` as a window function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_COUNT.html). Did you try the original answer? What was the error if it failed?

Comment: @pozs Thank you for your response. Yes I did try the original response- I get the following error: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause.

Comment: yes, [redshift is slightly different](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html). you'll need `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (after the `ORDER BY` clause) -- that's the default in PostgreSQL when you use `ORDER BY`, so it is usually omitted

Comment: Please don't tag question for Amazon Redshift with `postgresql. Although Redshift is based on (an extremely outdated version of) Postgres it has deviated substantially. See a similar discussion regarding other "spin-offs" here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/1822

Comment: @pozs So will you answer it?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto If it worked, I can answer it. But because I cannot test it myself, I'm not 100% sure. If you are sure/can test it, you can answer it if you like.

Comment: @pozs I can not test either. Leave the testing to the OP.

Comment: I'll test it and get back soon. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add frame_clause to the original answer since Redshift requires it:

```
select *
    , GREATEST(COUNT(case when state != 'miss' then 1 else null end) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) -1 , 0 ) as state_rank
from tbl;
```